# Magento 1.9.X: how to create custom order attribute?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, orders, product-attribute, custom-attributes

How can I create new order attribut using install script?
All my attempts failed and I don't know how to do this.
No one custom order attribute doesn't added to eav_attribute teble.
Help me pls)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example one I've used on a client site before.
This adds a simple quote & order attribute that gets populated by the customer in the frontend and then transferred over from the quote to the order (see the `etc/config.xml` example underneath for that part)

The install script:

```
<?php
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute(
    'order',
    'my_custom_attribute',
    [
        'type'          => 'varchar',
        'label'         => 'My Custom Attribute',
        'source'        => '',
        'backend'       => '',
        'frontend'      => '',
        'visible'       => true,
        'required'      => false,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'user_defined'  =>  true
    ]
);
$installer->addAttribute(
    'quote',
    'my_custom_attribute',
    [
        'type'          => 'varchar',
        'label'         => 'My Custom Attribute',
        'source'        => '',
        'backend'       => '',
        'frontend'      => '',
        'visible'       => true,
        'required'      => false,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'user_defined'  =>  true
    ]
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

The XML that converts quote attribute to order attribute:

```
<config>
    ....
    <global>
        ....
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>
                <my_custom_attribute><to_order>*</to_order></my_custom_attribute>
            </sales_convert_quote>

            <sales_convert_order>
                <my_custom_attribute><to_quote>*</to_quote></my_custom_attribute>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>
        ....
    </global>
    ....
</config>
```